# PhpStorm runs debugging in CLI mode instead of remote mode

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I got following problem. When I'm trying to run debugging in PhpStorm it seems to start debug session in quite arbitrary mode. Obviously I'm doing it wrong but sometimes it starts in remote mode - I got access to server global variables then but most of the time it starts in CLI mode - so also I assume my configuration for remote debug is okay.

I'm using marklets from this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/.

Here are the steps I follow:

1. I click on "Start listening connections..."
2. Then I click on "start debugger" bookmark where I saved the marklet and check if cookie is set and it is set in fact and has the same IDE id value I    set in configuration for remote debug.
3. Then I click on "Debug this page" marklet in bookmark or simply reload the page.
4. Finally I click on debug button in PhpStorm.

Then as I said - it sometimes starts in CLI mode, sometimes in remote mode.

I think the key to solve the problem is the dropdown list on the left from the run/debug buttons on top strip - I can choose there only between "edit configuration" and "index.php" with the icon which look the same like icon "PHP Script" in Edit Configurations window.

Also I got few tabs opened in top strip of debug panel but all of them also have the icon suggestion they are for Script mode...

How can I clearly set that I want to use remote debugging?
I am using PhpStorm 2017.1

Comment: **1)** If you are using bookmarklets (or xdebug browser extension) then you do not need to do #4 .. as it executes currently selected Run/Debug Configuration .. which might be of "PHP Script" type which runs PHP in CLI mode. **2)** In #3 -- you cannot just "reload the page" .. unless the xdebug cookie was already set earlier. In such case it's fine. **3)** If you want to use Debug button from IDE .. then you do not need bookmarklets etc (no need for #1, #2 & #3) - you just create Run/Debug Configuration of the right type (e.g. "PHP Web App"), choose it in dropdown box and hit Debug.

Comment: Just in case (has videos etc): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm . Searching "xdebug phpstorm" on YouTube will also bring quite few useful videos.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug PHP on webpage, the only thing you need to do is to start listening to remote connections. To do that, connect to the remote host via ssh with 9000 port forwarded (assuming your PHPStorm is listening on this one): `ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 <remote_host>`.
I believe Xdebug is running on the server.
If you're not the admin of the remote host, you can make sure things are set up by setting the following variables in the .htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
php_flag  xdebug.remote_enable on
php_value xdebug.remote_host 127.0.0.1
php_value xdebug.remote_port 9000
```

As for the marklets, you may try one of the on-market free extensions for the popular browsers (i.e. Xdebug helper)

If you want to debug CLI scripts on remote host, and you are not sure if it is all configured for that, apart from forwarding the port you cant try debugging by using the following arguments for php script:

```
php -dzend_extension=<path_to_xdebug_on_server, i.e /var/lib/apache2/modules/xdebug.so> -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=0 -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.remote_autostart=On -dxdebug.idekey=<your_ide_key> <script i.e. index.php>
```

Comment: PhpStorm supports Remote PHP Interpreters so debugging CLI script over SSH is part of the "PHP Script" type of Run/Debug Configuration (right mode will be used based on currently active PHP Interpreter -- whether it's local or remote one). **P.S.** I believe that by "remote" OP means "debugging web page" as opposed to the CLI -- as simple as that as he did not mention any remote servers etc.

Comment: PS indeed supports the Remote PHP interpreters and can run scripts by it's configuration as @LazyOne, but may I mention that if pa rameters do change often and if you want to benefit from all that shell CLI features, it may be useful to call the script manually and for that you need to add the parameters mentioned above.

Comment: I also believe that I may have been understood as a web page debugging and CLI have been run when the configured script has been accidentally set next to the debug button, but I wanted to make my answer complete by considering also this possibility